# Integral of logarithm times its derivative

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

The integral of $\int \frac{\ln{x}}{x}\, dx$ is right that is $\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{|x|}+c$?
I am in doubt if I have to consider or not the absolute value since I know that $\int \frac{1}{x}\, dx=\ln{|x|}+c$, but now I have to consider that  if I derive $\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{|x|}+c$ I obtain $\frac{\ln{|x|}}{x}$...

What do you think about it?

Comment: What is the base of the log you are using? $logx$ is different from $log_ex$.

Comment: Then you should have written $lnx$ since $log_ex=\ln x$

Comment: Anyway what is in your opinion the answer of my question?

Comment: Ok..but in this case I dont'have $x^2$ but only $x$...

Comment: @BBS You write as if your choice of notation was universally valid. It is not. Not even close.

Comment: The original problem $\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x} dx$ is undefined for $x \leq 0,$ because the integrand is undefined.

Comment: Ok so what is the answer?I would add the absolute value but then checking all with the derivative I have $\frac{\log{|x|}}{x}$ and not $\frac{\log{x}}{x}$

Comment: Someone can help me please? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule , you can also remember that :

$\int(f(x)^n)(f'(x))dx$=$\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}$ +$C$

Comment: Thanks I know this rule but  my problem and my question is: I have to consider the absolute value or not?

Comment: You don't have to take absolute value @Nik